# Using SPIRV-Reflect, how do I know that two descriptor bindings from different shaders are actually referring to the same buffer?

Tags: shader, hlsl, vulkan, spir-v

I have a vertex and a fragment shader, written in HLSL, which I compile into a SPIR-V binary using the [DirectX Shader Compiler](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler).

They both use a common `cbuffer` (which I want to treat as a `uniform` buffer) `ubo`. In order to construct a suitable `VkDescriptorSetLayout`, I want to use [SPIRV-Reflect](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Reflect) to obtain the necessary information about `ubo`.

While, I can create separate `spv_reflect::ShaderModule`'s `vertex_shader` and `fragment_shader` from the binary of my SPIR-V binaries of my shaders, I can only retrieve the information about existing descriptor bindings by calling `EnumerateDescriptorBindings()` on both `spv_reflect::ShaderModule`'s *individidually*.

They both yield the existence of `ubo`. But what I would want to do is tell the API that both shaders use the same uniform buffer `ubo`, i.e. create a `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding` for `ubo` and specify `VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT` and `VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT` for the `stageFlags` field.

But in order to do this I need to detect that both descriptor bindings yielded by the individual calls to `EnumerateDescriptorBindings` are referring to the same buffer. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how HLSL handles resource bindings, but presumably it has some mechanism to specify how a given resource is associated with whatever D3D12's resource model is. Presumably, the compiler you're using to generate SPIR-V either maps the D3D12 resource model to the Vulkan descriptor set/binding model or it makes a modification to HLSL language itself to allow the user to specify Vulkan descriptor sets/bindings for resources.

Either way, the SPIR-V generated by this process *must* have a descriptor set and a binding index for every descriptor resource it uses.

If the VS and the FS are both using the same UBO, then that means they *must* be written to use the same set+binding for that UBO. So when you're reflecting over multiple SPIR-V modules to aggregate the resources they use, you will need to aggregate these resources by set+binding. If two modules declare a resource with the same set and binding, then they are the same resource in the layout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if two `SpvReflectDescriptorBinding`'s (possibly obtained from different shader modules) have the same set and binding, then I aggregate them into one `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding`, right? Is it guaranteed that the numbering of the "set" indices goes from "zero" to "the total count of sets minus one"? Or can this value be freely set at some point?